# $_SESSION variable is null before I set it to null

Tags: php, switch-statement, session-variables

I have encountered a weird problem in my `php` code for a website I'm building:

I use the superglobal `$_SESSION['recent']` for creating alerts on my webpages. For example if a user tries to sign in, but gives a wrong password, the sign-in form will send its data to a file `login.php` which checks if all the data is correct. If the data is correct, it will set `$_SESSION['recent'] = 'login_succes'` (and a few other things so the user is signed in), else it will set `$_SESSION['recent'] = 'login_fail'`. Next it will return to the homepage with `header('location: http://www.example.com/')`.

In this homepage, there is a chunk of `php` code with a `switch` statement which checks for all possible `$_SESSION['recent']` values and will give an alert according to its value. This code looks a bit like this (I use bootstrap):

```
<?php switch ($_SESSION['recent']) { ?>
<?php case 'logout': ?>
<div class="container-fluid alert-fixed"><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="btn close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    You are signed out.
</div></div>
<?php break; case 'login_succes': ?>
<div class="container-fluid alert-fixed"><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    You are signed in
</div></div>
<?php break; case 'login_fail': ?>
... (similar alert message)
<?php break; case 'not_loggedin': ?>
...
<?php break; case 'admin_change_succes': ?>
...
<?php break; case 'admin_change_fail': ?>
...
<?php break; } $_SESSION['recent'] = null; ?>
```

So what I expect it would do, is check for any notifications and show an alert message if necessary. When that is done, it would set `$_SESSION['recent'] = null` so this message wont keep showing showing on and on.

**However**, this is the problem: this works for the first 3 cases (`logout`, `login_succes` and `login_fail`), but for all the other cases, the alerts don't show, **unless** I delete the line `$_SESSION['recent'] = null;` (which I obviously don't want to delete, because then the alert messages will keep on showing on reloading).

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to tackle the problem? If you need more information, just ask for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this file have `session_start();` at the start of the PHP file? Also, instead of $_SESSION['recent'] = null, you can just unset the variable, `unset($_SESSION['recent'])`.

Comment: Yes, it does have session_start() and using unset() doesn't work either...

Comment: echo out `$_SESSION['recent']` just before the switch statement and make sure it has the values that you are looking for.  Make sure the values match your case values.

Comment: I already did, as I mentioned in my question: the alerts work perfectly when I remove the line containing `$_SESSION['recent'] = null;`

Comment: @wohe1 I see no problem with your code and it should work as intended,but now it depends upon how the program control reaches this file.

Comment: I don't think it should matter, but the code in my question is included in all my webpages by using a php `require()` statement...

Comment: Can you make it `require_once` and check?

Comment: I tried `required_once()` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my own solution (all of the above didn't work for me...):

in my code I would check for errors like this:

```
if (!$_SESSION['uid'] or !$_SESSION['login']) {
    $_SESSION['recent'] = 'not_loggedin';
    header('location: http://my.domain.com/');
}
```

however, there is al lot of other code following that chunk. I thought that the `header` statement would stop the following code from being executed, but this does not seem to be the case, changing that code to the following works for me:

```
if (!$_SESSION['uid'] or !$_SESSION['login']) {
    $_SESSION['recent'] = 'not_loggedin';
    header('location: http://my.domain.com/');
    die();
}
```

Comment: Well, now it is clear what was the problem. As you assign null to your session variable after the end of `switch` operator, you need to prevent it somehow inside the `switch` body. `die()` is one option. Another option is to move `$_SESSION['recent'] = null;` above the `switch` block. But, you need to assign `$_SESSION['recent']` to variable first and use this variable as criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted in question looks like it should work as you expect. Most likely the problem is somewhere outside. To make sure that you have access to session value and clear it when script is done, you can do something like this

1. Add file `FlashMessages.php` with following content

   ```
   <?php
   class FlashMessages {
       private static $messages;
       private static $sessionStarted = false;

       public function __construct() {
           if (!self::$sessionStarted) {
               session_start();
               self::$sessionStarted = true;
           }
       }

       public function getMessage($name) {
           if (!array_key_exists($name, self::$messages)) {
               self::$messages[$name] = array_key_exists($name, $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION[$name] : null;
               unset($_SESSION[$name]);
           }

           return self::$messages[$name];
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the place where you need to do your checking, add next code

   ```
   <?php
   require_once('FlashMessages.php');
   $flashMessages = new FlashMessages();
   switch ($flashMessages->getMessage('recent')) {
       //...your code goes here
   }
   ```